# Не отображается первая запись

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

Делаю так

```
cmd.CommandText = "тут запрос";
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
DataTable schemaTable = new DataTable();
schemaTable.Load(dr);`
```

Это выполняется без первой строчки:

```
foreach (DataRow importRow in schemaTable.Rows)
{  
}
```

В запросе например 13 строк, но вижу я только 12, без первой (точно без первой, проверял изменяя сортировку ASC DESC), я так подозреваю, что `DataTable` первую считает как шапку. В общем вопрос, шо делать?

Даже вот так проверил:

```
MessageBox.Show(schemaTable.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

пишет 12, а по факту в запросе 13 строк.

[image: Скрин из Server Manager Studio]

Comment: Имхо, где-то вы ошибаетесь в своём коде. В документации к методу `Load` ничего такого не сказано. Проверил сейчас в своём коде - загружает именно столько строк, сколько есть, без всяких шапок.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov код перед вами, где может быть ошибка? `foreach` даже можно не учитывать, Вместо него просто `MessageBox` что бы понимать сколько строк в запросе.

Comment: В sql-запросе. В реальном количестве данных в БД.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил скрин из манагер студии результат этого запроса.

Comment: Хорошо. А если сделать запрос `cmd.CommandText = "select 1 a union select 2"` строчка одна?

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо, у меня между запросом и заполнением `DataTable` был такой код :`                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    checkColumnNull = dr["columnWidth"].ToString();
                }` если я его комментирую то дальше считает 13 строк. Мне пришлось его закомментировать что бы посчитать строки в запросе что вы мне дали.

Comment: Написал `static void Main() {
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection ("ds");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("",con);
cmd.CommandText = "select 1 a union select 2";
con.Open();
IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
DataTable schemaTable = new DataTable();
schemaTable.Load(dr);
foreach(DataRow importRow in schemaTable.Rows)
 Console.WriteLine("1");`
  ответ две строчки

Comment: `dr.Read()` читает одну строку. Естественно, остаётся на одну меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Победил методом тыка, не знаю почему так работает. Я сделал и все ок.

```
cmd.CommandText = "тут запрос";
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
DataTable schemaTable = new DataTable();
schemaTable.Load(dr);
```

Вместо этого

```
schemaTable.Load(dr);
```

Сделал так

```
schemaTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```